# ASP.NET Web Forms and MySql Entity Framework: "Nested transactions are not supported"

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have an ASP.NET web forms application, using the .Net Connector for MySql Entity Framework.

I've made a web application using MySql in the past, and never ran into this issue.

I'm currently getting ~20000 page views a day, and each day about 10 errors of 'Nested transactions are not supported.'

I can't figure out why it happens at all, and why it happens only once in awhile.

In a Master page Preload event I get an integer ID for the user and save it to a public variable:

```
using (var entity = new Entities())
                {
                    var user = entity.my_aspnet_users.Single(i => i.name == Context.User.Identity.Name);
                    UserID = user.id;
                    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath != "###" && HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath != "###")
                    {
                        if (user.Player == null)
                            Response.Redirect("###", true);
                        else
                            PlayerID = user.Player.PlayerID;
                    }
                }
```

And then on the page:

```
using (var entity = new Entities())
                            if (entity.Players.Count(i => ###) == 1)
                            {
                                var user = entity.my_aspnet_users.Single(i => i.id == Master.UserID);
                                if (user.Player == null)
                                {
                                    user.Player = entity.Players.Single(i => ###);
                                    entity.SaveChanges();
                                }
                                Response.Redirect("###", false);
                            }
```

The error gets thrown on SaveChanges().  I don't know why it only happens sometimes.  I also sometimes get the same error when a user registers on the site, though all this seems random and rare.

Anyway, for one, I thought nested transactions were allowed in MySql?  Is there a setting I need to set?  My MySql instance is 5.6.17 and I believe using default parameters - set up in Amazon RDS.

Does 'User.Identity.Name' access the database?  Do you have any idea on where I can look to solve this?

Here's the stack trace of some exceptions if helpful:

```
**Exception on example code:**
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: An error occurred while starting a transaction on the provider connection. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Nested transactions are not supported.

at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)

at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex)

at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso)

at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)

at System.Data.Common.DbConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)

at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.b__0(DbConnection t, BeginTransactionInterceptionContext c)

at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)

at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.BeginTransaction(DbConnection connection, BeginTransactionInterceptionContext interceptionContext)

at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.<>c__DisplayClassf.b__d()

at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)

at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginDbTransaction(IsolationLevel isolationLevel)

at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.BeginTransaction()

at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)

at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)

at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__27()

at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)

at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)

at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)

at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()

at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()

at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()

at ###.Account.###.ButtonSubmit###_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)

at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)

at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)

at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)

at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)

at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)

at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()

at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)

at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

at ASP.account_###.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



**Exception on creating a user:**
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Nested transactions are not supported.

at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ExceptionInterceptor.Throw(Exception exception)

at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Throw(Exception ex)

at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel iso)

at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.BeginTransaction()

at MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider.GetUser(Object providerUserKey, Boolean userIsOnline)

at MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider.GetUser(String username, Boolean userIsOnline)

at MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider.CreateUser(String username, String password, String email, String passwordQuestion, String passwordAnswer, Boolean isApproved, Object providerUserKey, MembershipCreateStatus& status)

at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.AttemptCreateUser()

at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.OnNextButtonClick(WizardNavigationEventArgs e)

at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)

at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CreateUserWizard.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e)

at System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args)

at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e)

at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)

at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)

at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)

at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)

at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)

at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()

at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)

at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

at ASP.register_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have likely run into [this bug in MySQL Connector/NET](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71502).

What triggers this bug:

1. Code calls for execution of query A
2. Transaction 1 for query A is started
3. Query A is executed and causes an error in MySQL
4. Transaction 1 is NOT rolled back
5. Code calls for execution of query B
6. Transaction 2 for query B is started
7. MySQL Connector/NET throws the exception

The bug is point 4: transaction 1 is left open after an error (or at least the connector is still convinced it's left open). Because of connection pooling, the code calling for query A and query B can be completely unrelated. Also, if the time between point 4 and 5 is long enough, the transaction *is* rolled back, hence the rareness and randomness.

Unfortunately there's no fix by MySQL yet. The only workaround that I know of is downloading the source code of Connector/NET and fixing/building it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think you are right



I ended up doing just that; most of my problems were with the MySql membership provider, so I used their source and took some queries out that I didn't need.  I do still have the problem, but it's much less frequent now, so I'm not as concerned