# EF6 Nested Transactions are not supported

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, dbcontext

I'm trying to make a simple database insert for just one table, the insert and the connections are working perfectly.The problem appears only when the exceptions arise for entering bad data.

Here is my code: (using MySql and EF6)

```
using (MaintenanceDB db = new MaintenanceDB())
        {
            try
            {
                employee employee = new employee
                {
                    ID = idTBA.textBox.Text,
                    EName = enTBA.textBox.Text,
                    AName = anTBA.textBox.Text,
                    CareerCode = careerCodeCBA.comboBox.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                    Specialization = specTBA.textBox.Text,
                    Mobile = mobileTBA.textBox.Text,
                    Telephone = teleTBA.textBox.Text,
                    Email = emailTBA.textBox.Text
                };
                db.employees.Add(employee);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.InnerException.InnerException.Message);
            }
            catch (EntityException exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exception.InnerException.Message);
            }
        }
```

so if the data entered correctly everything is smooth and fine, but if I entered duplicate ID for example the first time it's going to the first catch block and tell me there is a duplicate , at this point there is something wrong, it seems the connection isn't closed here (Despite using finally and dispose on db), the next time I hit the save button the error "Nested Transactions are not supported" appears, and then the db closes and I'm able to enter new data!

I tried opening the connection manually or starting a transaction and closing it manually as I found in few posts here but nothing seems to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

It seems like [a mysql bug...., #71502](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71502)

> [27 Feb 15:54] Raif Atef
>
> This bug is due to a bug in the MySqlTransaction class.

Comment: Indeed. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320679/asp-net-web-forms-and-mysql-entity-framework-nested-transactions-are-not-suppo/29265962#29265962